# How can you change scrollbar color using Internet Explorer's CSS for when hovered?

Tags: css, scrollbar, internet-explorer-11

I've learned a lot of CSS properties on my school website. But how can you change the color of the scrollbar for when it's hovered?

Example:

```
html {
    scrollbar-arrow-color: white;
    scrollbar-face-color: green;
    scrollbar-face-hover-color: darkGreen;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: black;
    scrollbar-track-color: black;
}
```

Maybe it's also possible to change the background of the arrow buttons.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.

`::-webkit-scrollbar-face{ background: black;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-face:hover {background: darkGreen;}`

This colors the face in a different color when hovering.

Comment: I think it should now work in the latest version of Microsoft Edge. Doesn't it.